# Why future is not getting complete?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get all the document inside this collection which much these query - I'm receiving all the documents successfully but the future never ends.

I tried WhenComplete but still not working.

```
Future<Null> getOldVac(anId) async {
    print("getOldVac");
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .document(userId)
        .collection("animals")
        .document(anId)
        .collection("anMedication")
        .where("type", isEqualTo: "vac")
        .where("result", isEqualTo: "")
        .snapshots()
        .forEach((onValue) {
      print(onValue);
    }).then((onValue) {
      print("Done");
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    });
  }
```

I need to print "Done" once all the future is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something, can be the `null` that you are using or a `void` or throw some error.

try to put `return` in the front of your `await` like this:

```
return await Firestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .document(userId)
        .collection("animals")
        .document(anId)
        .collection("anMedication")
        .where("type", isEqualTo: "vac")
        .where("result", isEqualTo: "")
        .snapshots()
        .forEach((onValue) {
      print(onValue);
      return null;
    }).then((onValue) {
      print("Done");
      return null;
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
      throw onError;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `promises` with `async await`!

Comment: Can you give an example for both plz?